# Selenium script with pyvirtualdisplay and Xvfb not working on cron on linux vm

Tags: selenium, cron, xvfb, pyvirtualdisplay

I have a selenium script which uses pyvirtualdisplay.Display with visible=0. The script runs fine when run manually but fails when run using cron job. I think it is due to the Xvfb and pyvirtualdisplay but I can't seem to fix it. The crontab command is * * * * * /python3 /location/to/the/script

Comment: What error do you see?

Comment: Chrome failed to start : exited abnormally. The process started from chrome location /ursr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.

Comment: This is the same error when I dont add the pyvirtualdisplay or put visible variable in Display to 1.